how to create custom palette with angular material?
I'm new user to angular material2 and i try to define custom theme for my app.
So i want to define a palette for my custom theme:
@use "@angular/material" as mat;
@include mat.core();

$m2-custom-palette: (
  50: #e1f5fe,
  100: #b3e5fc,
  200: #81d4fa,
  300: #81d4fa,
  400: #29b6f6,
  500: #03a9f4,
  600: #039be5,
  700: #0288d1,
  800: #0277bd,
  900: #01579b,
  contrast: (
    50: #000,
    100: #000,
    200: #000,
    300: #fff,
    400: #fff,
    500: #fff,
    600: #fff,
    700: #fff,
    800: #fff,
    900: #fff,
  ),
);
$my-primary: mat.m2-define-palette(mat.$m2-light-blue, 500);

After i define $my-primary variable appears error: "Undefined variable mat.$m2-light-blue".
I'm confused. Pls help.

The error happens because $m2-light-blue doesn't exist. Instead, you should define your custom color palette and use it directly. Here's a simplified fix:


@use "@angular/material" as mat;

//  Angular Material core here
@include mat.core();

// your custom palette here
$m2-custom-palette: (
  50: #e1f5fe,
  100: #b3e5fc,
  200: #81d4fa,
  300: #81d4fa,
  400: #29b6f6,
  500: #03a9f4,
  600: #039be5,
  700: #0288d1,
  800: #0277bd,
  900: #01579b,
  contrast: (
    50: #000,
    100: #000,
    200: #000,
    300: #fff,
    400: #fff,
    500: #fff,
    600: #fff,
    700: #fff,
    800: #fff,
    900: #fff,
  ),
);

//   primary color 
$my-primary: mat.define-palette($m2-custom-palette, 500);

// put primary +accent +  warn palettes here
$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $my-primary,
    accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette),
    warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette),
  ),
));

// Include  theme style here
@include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme);



This should resolve your issue. You're basically defining your custom colors and then applying them properly.
